# Adding multiple ports to pop3 service (freebsd)

Tags: linux, unix, freebsd, ports

I am looking to add a few additional ports to the pop3 service on a freebsd server.

Is it possible to simply add entries to the /etc/services file to reflect the additional ports ?

like

```
pop3            110/tcp    #Post Office Protocol - Version 3
pop3            110/udp    #Post Office Protocol - Version 3
...
pop3            1211/tcp    #Post Office Protocol - Version 3
pop3            1211/udp    #Post Office Protocol - Version 3
```

Or do I need to create a new entry in the inetd.conf file for a service with a new name
and then add it to the services file ??

like :

```
pop12    stream  tcp     nowait  root    /usr/local/libexec/ipop3d       ipop3d
```

and then add to the services file:

```
pop12            1211/tcp    #Post Office Protocol - Version 3
pop12            1211/udp    #Post Office Protocol - Version 3
```

--- Also after all is said and done (assuming one of these is the correct way).
is it enough to only execute :

```
refresh -s inetd
```

to effect the changes ?

Thanks a bunch
Larry

Comment: thanks for the formatting help fedorqui

Comment: what pop3 daemon do you use? Usually this should be done in the daemons configuration file.